# Ruby - TicTacToe Finding a Winner

Tags: r, ruby, terminal, tic-tac-toe

I know TicTacToe questions have been posted before but after looking at the other posts and a lot of online research I am still stumped. I Would really appreciate some help.

Overall I can't figure out why the appropriate winner is not showing up and sometimes nil seems to be given a value as equal to "X" or "O". I'm also having trouble with figuring out Cat's Game, but I think I'm getting close.

Here is all my code, please let me know if any additional info can help find a resolution:

```
class TicTacToe
def initialize
    row1 = [nil,nil,nil]
    row2 = [nil,nil,nil]
    row3 = [nil,nil,nil]
    @row1 = row1
    @row2 = row2
    @row3 = row3
end

def show_board
    print @row1
    puts
    print @row2
    puts
    print @row3
    puts
end

def prompt
    print " >>> "
end

def turn
    puts "Pick row #"
    print prompt
    row_choice = gets.chomp
    @row_choice = row_choice
    puts "Pick column #"
    print prompt
    column_choice = gets.chomp
    @column_choice = column_choice
end

def winner
    print "checking for winner..."
    if @row1[0] == @row1[1] && @row1[2]
        puts "We have a winner1!"
        replay()
    elsif @row2[0] == @row2[1] && @row2[2]
        puts "We have a winner2!"
        replay()
    elsif @row3[0] == @row3[1] && @row3[2]
        puts "We have a winner3!"
        replay()
    elsif @row1[0] == @row2[1] && @row3[2]
        puts "We have a winner4!"
        replay()
    elsif @row3[0] == @row2[1] && @row1[2]
        puts "We have a winner5!"
        replay()
    elsif @row1[0] == @row2[0] && @row3[0]
        puts "We have a winner6!"
        replay()
    elsif @row1[1] == @row2[1] && @row3[1]
        puts "We have a winner7!"
        replay()
    elsif @row1[2] == @row2[2] && @row3[2]
        puts "We have a winner8!"
        replay()
    #elsif @row1 && @row2 && @row3 != nil
    #   puts "Catsgame - no one wins!"
    #   replay()
    else
        puts "nope"
    end
end 

def replay
    puts "---------------------"
    puts "Would you like to play again? YES or NO"
    select = gets.chomp
    if select.downcase == "yes"
        @row1 = [nil,nil,nil]
        @row2 = [nil,nil,nil]
        @row3 = [nil,nil,nil]
        player1()
    else
        Process.exit(0)
    end
end

def player1
    puts "---------------------"
    puts "It is Player 1's turn"
    turn()
    if @row_choice == 1.to_s
        if @row1[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "O"
            puts
            puts "Space is taken by Player 2"
            player1()
        elsif @row1[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "X"
            puts
            puts "You are already in this space"
            player1()   
        else
            @row1[@column_choice.to_i - 1] = "X"
        end
    elsif @row_choice == 2.to_s
        if @row2[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "O"
            puts
            puts "Space is taken by Player 2"
            player1()
        elsif @row2[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "X"
            puts
            puts "You are already in this space"
            player1()   
        else
            @row2[@column_choice.to_i - 1] = "X"
        end
    elsif @row_choice == 3.to_s
        if @row3[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "O"
            puts
            puts "Space is taken by Player 2"
            player1()
        elsif @row3[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "X"
            puts
            puts "You are already in this space"
            player1()   
        else
            @row3[@column_choice.to_i - 1] = "X"
        end
    else
        puts
        puts "Pick 1, 2, or 3"
        player1()
    end
    show_board()
    winner()
    player2()
end

def player2
    puts "---------------------"
    puts "It is Player 2's turn"
    turn()
    if @row_choice == 1.to_s
        if @row1[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "X"
            puts
            puts "Space is taken by Player 1"
            player2()
        elsif @row1[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "O"
            puts
            puts "You are already in this space"
            player2()   
        else
            @row1[@column_choice.to_i - 1] = "O"
        end
    elsif @row_choice == 2.to_s
        if @row2[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "X"
            puts
            puts "Space is taken by Player 1"
            player2()
        elsif @row2[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "O"
            puts
            puts "You are already in this space"
            player2()   
        else
            @row2[@column_choice.to_i - 1] = "O"
        end
    elsif @row_choice == 3.to_s
        if @row3[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "X"
            puts
            puts "Space is taken by Player 1"
            player2()
        elsif @row3[@column_choice.to_i - 1] == "O"
            puts
            puts "You are already in this space"
            player2()   
        else
            @row3[@column_choice.to_i - 1] = "O"
        end
    else
        puts
        puts "Pick 1, 2, or 3"
        player2()
    end
    show_board()
    winner()
    player1()
end
end

puts "The game begins!"
new_game = TicTacToe.new()
new_game.show_board()
new_game.player1()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your if statements aren't doing what you think.  You need a == b && a == c, not a == b && c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you'd ideally check for who the winner is -

```
 if @row1[0] == @row1[1] && @ro1[0] == @row1[2] && @row1[0] == "X"
     puts "Player 1 Wins!"
     replay()
 elsif @row1[0] == @row1[1] && @row1[0] == @row1[2] && @row1[0] == "O"
     puts "Player 2 Wins!"
     replay()
 .....
```

You'll also want to put the replay function above the winner function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for two days, you rock! It's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
if @row1[0] == @row1[1] && @row[0] == @row1[2]
    puts "We have a winner1!"
    replay()
elsif @row2[0] == @row2[1] && @row2[0] == @row2[2]
    puts "We have a winner2!"
    replay()
```

and so on.
Right now, you are checking that the first and second items are equal, and that the third simply exists. What you want is to check both the second and third items against the first to determine if they are all equal.